# How old do you have to be to get into Canada by yourself?

Tags: canada, regulations

I am 17 and I'm going to Canada to get my truck worked on and I need to know if I can get over there by myself and back and can I use my birth certificate and driver's license? It's just me driving my self with my dad in a different car so he can pick me up.

Comment: To clarify, are you driving yourself, or travelling with others? Do you have a passport or just a driver's license?

Comment: And I assume you're an American citizen, if you're asking about going 'over there' (ie over the land border?)?

Comment: yes im driving my self

Comment: *to get my truck worked on* - What can they do there that they can't do here?

Comment: Leaving aside the question of whether Canada will admit you, if you are a U.S. citizen you will need a passport or [other WHTI-approved document](http://www.getyouhome.gov/) like a [NEXUS card](http://www.cbp.gov/xp/cgov/travel/trusted_traveler/nexus_prog/nexus.xml) or [EDL](http://www.dmv.ny.gov/edl-main.htm) to be readmitted (or spend a long time getting interviewed by CBP).

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty good description of what is required to enter Canada for US citizens on the [US Department of State website](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_1082.html#entry_requirements).  According to it you will need a proof of citizenship and a proof of identity.  Which a Driver's license and an Original Birth certificate might suffice.  On top of this because you're under 18 you might also have to have a notarized letter from your parents allowing you to leave the country.

Now the question becomes how will you be able to re-enter the US.  As @choster pointed out there is a [Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative](http://getyouhome.gov/html/lang_eng/index.html) that is supposed to make travel easier.  That being said you will need a [NEXUS Card](http://getyouhome.gov/html/lang_eng/eng_edl.html) or an [EDL](http://getyouhome.gov/html/EDL_map.html) along with you [original birth certificate](http://travel.state.gov/passport/get/first/first_830.html#PrimaryEvCitiz) to re-enter.  Something tells me that you're not in possession of the [Nexus Card](http://getyouhome.gov/html/lang_eng/eng_edl.html) because it is usually obtain by frequent travelers between US and Canada.

Also according to [WHTI](http://getyouhome.gov/html/lang_eng/eng_ttp.html) site only 4 states in the US issue the EDLs and the more likely scenario in order to obtain one you will need to be in possession of a [US Passport](http://www.dmv.ny.gov/forms/id44edl.pdf), though you don't have to but it makes things easier.

So in all I would suggest getting a Passport or doing the work in the US might be a lot easier if not cheaper.